# How to make repeading 3D ball on Y coordinate in processing?

Tags: java, processing

I was making an animation on processing. Then, I confused about on a problem. I prepare a simple code for you. Also, I think the question can helpfull for the beginners.

```java
PShape ball;
float ballSpeed = random(0.5, 1);
float ballSize = random(5, 10);
float x = 200, y = 300, z = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P3D);
  noStroke();         // That's for "not see details on sphere"
  ball = createShape(SPHERE, ballSize);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(x, y, z); // rotate the ball
  println(y);         // checking the y coordinates
  fill(255);
  shape(ball);
  y -= ballSpeed;     // the ball can go to top
}
```

So, I want to make a condition for if the ball reach the 100, the ball should return or start its first position and then again it should go to 100 again. I tried many if conditions but couldn’t figure out it.
If you help me I will be happy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invert `ballSpeed`, if the `y` coordinate of the ball is less or equal 100 respectively greater or equal 300:

```java
y -= ballSpeed;
if (y <= 100 || y >= 300) {
    ballSpeed = -ballSpeed;
}
```

Note the ball is moving upwards. When the ball reaches 100, `ballSpeed` is inverted, the ball changes direction and moves downwards. If the ball reaches is original position (300), `ballSpeed` is inverted again and the ball changes the direction again.

---

If you want that the ball restarts at 300, when it reaches a `y` coordinate of 100, then it is sufficient to set `y = 300`:

```java
y -= ballSpeed;
if (y <= 100) {
    y = 300;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rabbid76 your answer was true.However, I wrote my question wrong. Sorry for that. English is not my native language. The ball shouldn't return, when the ball reach the 100 it should start from 300 again.

Comment: @Daymnn I've extended the answer.